# Pure HTML works fine but problems come while implementing it in react

Tags: html, reactjs, axios

The following HTML code is working fine and is redirecting me to the action URL on submit.

```
<body>
    <form action="https://uat.esewa.com.np/epay/main" method="POST">
    <input value="100" name="tAmt" type="hidden">
    <input value="90" name="amt" type="hidden">
    <input value="5" name="txAmt" type="hidden">
    <input value="2" name="psc" type="hidden">
    <input value="3" name="pdc" type="hidden">
    <input value="EPAYTEST" name="scd" type="hidden">
    <input value="ee2c3ca1-696b-4cc5-a6be-2c40d929d453" name="pid" type="hidden">
    <input value="http://merchant.com.np/page/esewa_payment_success?q=su" type="hidden" name="su">
    <input value="http://merchant.com.np/page/esewa_payment_failed?q=fu" type="hidden" name="fu">
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

I tried implementing it in reactjs as follows-

```
var params= {
    amt: 100,
    psc: 0,
    pdc: 0,
    txAmt: 0,
    tAmt: 100,
    pid: "ee2c3ca1-696b-4cc5-a6be-2c40d929d453",
    scd: "EPAYTEST",
    su: "http://merchant.com.np/page/esewa_payment_success",
    fu: "http://merchant.com.np/page/esewa_payment_failed"
}
const payNowHandler = async () => {
    const config = {
      

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }
    const { data} = await axios.post(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://uat.esewa.com.np/epay/main`,
      {
        params,
        config,
      }
    )
    console.log('the data is', data)
    
  }
```

I have used cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com just for solving cors issue and I think it is not a big problem here.I am getting the pure HTML content as response with status code 200 and this makes sense as well. I want to redirect myself to some specific route with that HTML content received as response. How can I do that???

Comment: which route is it in your react or outdoor application?

Comment: @Daphaz I am using react

Comment: yes i know, but  the redirection you want is in your app like /some-route or to https:// uat.esewa.com.np/epay/main

Comment: @Daphaz I want to be  redirected  to the page https:// uat.esewa.com.np/epay/main which is an external link. I am getting the content to be displayed on that page as HTML response.

Comment: @Daphaz try running my html content in a HTML file and see the redirected url and its content. I want that to happen brother.

Comment: @UpendraDhamala have you solved the esewa cors problem. I am currently stucked there..

Answer (score 0):

The way you try post request in axios is different

```
export const performPost = function (url, data = undefined, queryString = '') {
  return axios({
    method: "post",
    url: url + (queryString ? "?" + queryString : ""),
    data,
    headers: {...getHeaders()},
  });
};
```

and your headers object can go like this

```
const getHeaders = () => ({
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
});
```

And call your performPost as

```
performPost('url',postbody)
          .then(response => {
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how you get the submission event of your form normally we use the onSubmit parameter in jsx like

```
<form onSubmit={payNowHandler}>
 ...
</form>
```

but your form doesn't seem to be generated from react, anyway I can say that there is a problem in the use of axios

axios waits for `axios.post(url, data, config)` and you don't send any data you can use an empty object or null it seems to me

so your function should look like this

```
const config = {
  headers: {
   Accept: "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  params: {
    amt: 100,
    psc: 0,
    pdc: 0,
    txAmt: 0,
    tAmt: 100,
    pid: "ee2c3ca1-696b-4cc5-a6be-2c40d929d453",
    scd: "EPAYTEST",
    su: "http://merchant.com.np/page/esewa_payment_success",
    fu: "http://merchant.com.np/page/esewa_payment_failed"
  }
};

const payNowHandler = async () => {

  try{
    const {data} = await axios.post(
     'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://uat.esewa.com.np/epay/main',
     {},
     {...config}
    );

    console.log('the data is', data);

  }catch(error){
   console.log(error);
  }
};
```